# Possible to highlight without zoom in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to select an area of a chart and not zoom in? I'd like to get the bars that are covered in the highlighted area. I tried several different ways, the highlight won't show up unless I specify `zoomType` to something and there doesn't seems to be any events generated that I could hook onto with the highlighting or range selection.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to select area without zoom by disabling default functionalities in the selection callback.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n46fghsL/

```
    selection: function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
        var text,
            label;
        if (event.xAxis) {
            text = 'min: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(event.xAxis[0].min, 2) + ', max: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(event.xAxis[0].max, 2);
        } else {
            text = 'Selection reset';
        }
        label = this.renderer.label(text, 100, 120)
            .attr({
                fill: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                padding: 10,
                r: 5,
                zIndex: 8
            })
            .css({
                color: '#FFFFFF'
            })
            .add();

        setTimeout(function () {
            label.fadeOut();
        }, 1000);
    }
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.selection

Comment: If my intent is to select the data points under the highlighted area, is this the right way to go? I'm thinking of putting my own logic inside the `selection` function and manually selecting the points there. Or am I doing something overly complicated?

Comment: @codenamezero I think that it is the right way to achieve your requirements. The second demo from the API from my answer has implemented something similiar: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-selection-points/